# faceted search for ipad / iphone / android platform

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, search, mobile

i have been playing around with apache SOLR since last 3 weeks and very happy with the results. now we are trying to replicate the faceted search we offer on our website to our ipad, iphone and android apps

since these apps have their local sqlite db for offline access, i cannot go for an online xml web service based approach to compute the faceted search results

wondering if there is any lightweight solution like apache SOLR for tablet / mobile platforms which can index the data from sqlite?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, currently there are no Objective-C frameworks for faceted search on iOS devices.